# Tomcat crashing with no error

Tags: debian, logging, tomcat

I am running tomcat 7 on debian 7.9 dedicated server with several applications running on it and last time tomcat behavior is really strange.

First after tomcat starts it takes all the assigned RAM (7 GB) and after that the RAM usage is slowly decreasing down to 5 GB and after an hour of runtime it crashes completely with no error in any of the tomcat logs (manager, access log, catalina, localhost).

This error cannot be caused by any app because I have tested them on my computer with netbeans + glassfish server and after start my apps take only 800 MB RAM not 7 GB so this has to be some kind of tomcat error.

Should I try to update to tomcat 8 ? I am not sure if it helps because like I said there is no error it just stops running and I have to start tomcat again manually.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Tomcat generate crash dump in home directory with the name hs_err_pid_number.log. Can you please check latest log and paste here.

Comment: There is no log in tomcat home directory.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM just can't take all available RAM. Did you set something in `CATALINA_OPTS`, `JAVA_OPTS` or the `startup.sh`?

The parameter looks like this:

```
-Xms<size>
```

If the JVM crashes you should have a `hs_err_pid` file somewhere. It is usually hard to read but after some digging it has helped me in the few cases where something went wrong.

It should be in the working directory of your tomcat directory, unless otherwise set, this is `CATALINA_HOME`.